# How to show jQuery UI datepicker on click of <button> and replace the <button> text with selected date?

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btndate">Date</button>
```

I want to show jQuery UI datepicker on click of above button and replace the text "Date" with the selected date in the calendar. I don't have any textbox in the HTML, only `<button>`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btndate").click(function(){
        // Required code...
    });
});
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Can you use hiddenfield?

Comment: You mean we need to use text field as a hidden field? Without using text field, can't it be possible to show datepicker?

Comment: yes, using hidden field

Comment: oh ok, so we can use either hidden text field or even hidden field to trigger datepicker, right?

Comment: yes, the answer is already there you can check that.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you could make use of the input field that jQueryUI datepicker expects but just hide it. You can then copy the selected date to your button when the date changes.

Here is an example of how you would do that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      $("#btndate").html($(this).val())
    }
  });
  $("#btndate").click(function() {
    $(".date").datepicker("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.date{
  visibility:hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btndate">Date</button>
<input class="date" type="text" />
```

**EDIT**

It seems that datepicker really doesn't like working with a hidden input, it breaks on the second click.

the alternative is to hide it with `visibility:hidden` (even `display:none` doesn't work)

The updated answer includes this fix

Comment: oh, why did you remove your very first solution?

Comment: it was just bloated with css

Comment: but for me it was working pretty fine for display:none text field as well as input hidden field. But I noticed one issue - the order of HTML does matter. The following order doesn't work for me: `<button type="button" id="btndate">Date</button><input class="date" type="hidden" />` If i reverse them, then it does work. why?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the way the datepicker is rendered in the dom. I suspect it's looking for `position.left` to get the location of where to place it.  I was getting `cannot find property left of undefined`

Comment: may be... i also noticed it doesn't only stop on html order change but does also stop working if jquery code order is changed